# How to imprt impex through cronjob

Tags: cron, sap-commerce-cloud, impex

I need to import impex lines through cronjob for which I have written below code,
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYGUm.png)

I am writing this code in public PerformResult perform(final CronJobModel arg0). If I import this impex manaully from hac, it gets imported successfully. Following is the error I am getting on logs,

[log error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vw94N.png)

Thanks...

Comment: Please don't post images of your error message. Copy and paste it into your question. Same for your code.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend using ModelService for implementations like this.

```
secFilingsComponent.setName("2014 Filings 1");
secFilingsComponent.setUrlLink("#");
secFilingsComponent.setSlots(CollectionUtils.union(oldSlots, newSlots));
modelService.save(secFilingsComponent);
```

If the changes you want to do should only be executed once, I would recommend using hmc/backoffice and do them manually or execute the Impex in the hac:
https://localhost:9002/hac/console/impex/import

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to replace `cmsComponents(&componentRef)` by `cmsComponents(uid,$contentCV)` in the first INSERT_UPDATE.